# SSH not working after setting static IP

Tags: pi-3, ssh, static-ip

I am using SSH to access my Pi 3 which is connected to my home router via Ethernet. It gets an IP address via DHCP from the router and I connect to it using my laptop installed with Ubuntu without any issues.

I followed the instructions [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/networking-lessons/rpi-static-ip-address/) to give my Pi a static IP and it worked fine. The Pi can be pinged with its new IP now, but I cant access the Pi via SSH on my Ubuntu laptop anymore.

I removed the SSH key from Ubuntu using `rm ~/.ssh` but that did not help.

When I take out the SD card and change the `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` to its previous DHCP setting the SSH connection works fine again.

```
z@vaio:~$ ssh pi@192.168.2.10
The authenticity of host '192.168.2.10 (192.168.2.10)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:2uehpaRWZyOrjJpJbQR1bcj9RWBaeQA6DSijkicYago.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.2.10' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
pi@192.168.2.10's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
pi@192.168.2.10's password:
```

Comment: Did you restart the Pi and or SSh after changing the IP address change?

Comment: yes, several times!

Comment: do i need to remove ssh keys on RPI ? how?

Comment: With all those words you may have missed the key word ",host,". You need the host key in your known_hosts file. The host keys are in /etc/ssh

Comment: shall i delete them from my ubuntu?

Comment: z@vaio:/etc/ssh$ ls
moduli            ssh_host_dsa_key.pub    ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
ssh_config        ssh_host_ecdsa_key      ssh_host_rsa_key
sshd_config       ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub  ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
ssh_host_dsa_key  ssh_host_ed25519_key    ssh_import_id

Comment: no "known_hosts" named file in /etc/ssh !